# Text Adventure quits after first choice?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to make a simple text adventure game. The game runs, but after you type in the first option it just exits the program like you are done.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Adventure {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7;

        System.out.println("What shop do you need to go to? the 'Armor Shop' or the 'Weapon   Shop'?");
        c1 = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println();

        if(c1 == "Armor Shop") {
            System.out.println("Do you need 'Light' or 'Heavy' armor?");
            c2 = keyboard.next();
            if(c2 == "Light") {
                System.out.println("Do you want 'Hide' or 'Leather'?");
                c4 = keyboard.next();
                if(c4 == "Hide") {
                    System.out.println("Here is your hide armor");
                }
                else if(c4 == "Leather") {
                    System.out.println("Here is your leather armor");
                }
                else if(c2 == "Heavy") {
                    System.out.println("Do you want 'Chain' or 'Iron'?");
                    c5 = keyboard.next();
                    if(c5 == "Chain") {
                        System.out.println("Here is your chain armor");
                    }
                    else if(c5 == "Iron") {
                        System.out.println("Here is your iron armor");
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(c1 == "Weapon Shop") {
                System.out.println("Do you need a 'Sword' or a 'Bow'?");
                c3 = keyboard.next();
                if(c3 == "Sword") {
                    System.out.println("Do you want a 'Longsword' or a 'Shortsword'?");
                    c6 = keyboard.next();
                    if(c6 == "Longsword") {
                        System.out.println("Here is your longsword");
                    }
                    else if(c6 == "Shortsword") {
                        System.out.println("Here is your shortsword");
                    }
                }
                else if(c3 == "Bow") {
                    System.out.println("Do you want 'Oak' or 'Elven'?");
                    c7 = keyboard.next();
                    if(c7 == "Oak") {
                        System.out.println("Here is your oak bow");
                    }
                    else if(c7 == "Elven") {
                        System.out.println("Here is your elven bow");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to coding and still learning so any help would be much appreciated. I tried to look everywhere for an answer but could not find one.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Cool that you are attempting to make a game. Your current code is exiting after input because there is no mechanism to loop back up to your program entrance. Once the top level `if(c1 == "Armor Shop")` statement is fully evaluated, the program exits, as expected.

Comment: Also, your game is going to quickly become unmanageable if all your program flow is handled with `if`/`else` statements. Maybe take a look at [something like this](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/text-adventure/) first?

Comment: This may not be the cause of your problem, but never compare Strings with `==` but instead use `.equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)`. The reason is that `==` compares if two variables refer to the one same object, something you don't care about, while the equals method checks if the Strings hold the same chars in the same order. And you do care about that.

Comment: You need a loop of some kind. Probably a do/while.

Comment: Consider learning loops and methods first before tackling this. Else you'll be creating one huge main method, one with much unintelligible cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I am learning java through http://programmingbydoing.com/ and the lesson i am on said to make a simple text adventure using nested if statements. I have not made it to the loop section yet so i do not know how to use them. I didnt think i would need them since i havent made it there, but i will figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

By calling **java.util.Scanner.next()** you are just calling for the next token on the same entry.

The default delimiter is whitespaces so when you type "**Armor Shop**" and enter what will happen is that **Scanner.next()** will return "**Armor**" and the next call to **Scanner.next()** will return "**Shop**".

I don't think that is the behaviour you want, so what you could do is call **Scanner.nextLine()** which will return the full content of what was typed and so it would read "**Armor Shop**" and at the next call wait for user input.

Comment: You try to help people and that's what you get. For you info **Hovercraft Full Of Eels** you need +50 rep to add comments.

Comment: And you've got them. For your information, I've up-voted this answer.